# What data Apache Spark ships to execution nodes

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, scapy, pyspark

I use Apache Spark to find patterns/attaks in Ethernet communications. I am concerned about the amount of data Spark sends to the YARN/Hadoop execution nodes.

I use Scapy inside my map function (See code below). If it is not installed on the execution nodes will Spark ship the entire module to them? Or in such case the task won't be executed? Or end up in failure? Is there any way to control this behavior?

What will happen if my map function access any global objects? Are the objects shipped to the workers? Or there is some kind of error/unexpected behavior?

Here is an example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def ExtractIP(rawEther):
    from scapy.layers.inet import Ether, IP

    eth = Ether(rawEther)
    # May not be IP (for example ARP)
    try:
        return eth[IP].fields['src']
    except:
        return '0.0.0.0'

def main():
    # Init Spark
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    # Load data
    cap = sc.sequenceFile("hdfs://master/user/art/Data.seq")

    # Get raw Ethernet message
    raw_msgs = cap.values()

    # Get the source IP address using Scapy
    msg_ip = raw_msgs.map(ExtractIP)

    # Print the number of target IP messages
    print msg_ip.filter(lambda srcIp: srcIp == '10.1.1.100').count()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables referenced in closures are shipped automatically to the worker nodes but you have take care of the dependencies.

There multiple ways to handle this:

1. install dependencies / place on a `PYTHONPATH` on each worker node
2. use `pyFiles` argument when you create [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=sparkcontext#pyspark.SparkContext) or [`addPyFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=sparkcontext#pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile) method on an existing one
3. use `--py-files` argument of `spark-submit`

If dependencies are large or require some external libraries the first approach is probably optimal. If build your own modules you may prefer one of the `pyFiles` solutions instead.